# Resteasy GET - JSON in QueryString

Tags: json, get, query-string, resteasy

I would like to pass JSON arrays and list of JSON objects to Reasteasy GET method in query string. How can I access them in the service method?

For example on array, if the parameter name is "employeeId", I would like to pass
?employeeId=[1,2,3] 
instead of passing
?employeeId=1&employeeId=2&employeeId=3

For list of objects, I would like to pass something like
?parameter=[{val1, val2},{val1, val2},{val1, val2}]

How can I get these correctly in the server side method?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Path annotation and PathParam annotation to pick up the input values

```
@Path(/path/EmployeeIdArray)
public void someMethod(@PathParam("EmployeeIdArray")String[] employeeIdArray){

}
```

using this you can access it as

> GET /path/[{val1, val2},{val1, val2},{val1, val2}]